# How to interpret method parameters in node.js documentation

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was reading the documentation for the HTTP module in nodejs, and I'm a bit confused with the syntax used to display parameters. For example, here's the syntax for the `createServer` method.

```
http.createServer([options][, requestListener])
```

Could someone break down what the arguments mean? Specifically, what does the comma before "request listener" indicate?

Another one that's even more confusing to me:

```
http.request(url[, options][, callback])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Square brackets mean a parameter is optional.

Comment: The comma is the normal separator between arguments.

Comment: Had a full answer for the guy that could be helpful.... sadly we are very quick here with closing questions :/

Comment: `http.request(url[, options][, callback])`
http.request gets three params:
1. url - required
2. options - optional
3. callback - optional

`http.createServer([options][, requestListener])`
http.createServer gets two params:
1. options - optional
2. requestListener - optional

In both functions make sure to keep the order of the params. So `url` is first, then `options`, then `callback`.
Make sure to read what each parameter expects. In this case `url` expects a string, `options` an object with different options, `callback` a function to run once the server is successfully created.

Comment: Actually one additional question @URogel: I called the `createServer()` method just using the callback and it seemed to work. I just put the callback straight into the function argument without making an effort to skip the first argument ([options]). How does this work? I assumed I would have had to pass in "undefined" to skip that argument. Am I missing something?

Comment: @bugsyb if you give second argument a function then createServer knows it is not options but the callback function. But don't count on this behavior for every builtin function.